# Algorithm to find combinations of coins that satisfies a predicate?

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

I have the following:

**Colors:** Red, Blue and Green

**Alphabets:** From A to Z

Now suppose I can form coins using the above two, each coin will have one of the colors as background color and one of the letters.

The background color of the coin is either Red, Blue or Green, and the letter on the coin each color can have is predefined, each color will take specific amount of the alphabets.

Red background coins will have: S, D, A, C, Y, U, L, J, O

Blue background coins will have: F, T, V, M, K

Green background coins will have: G, X, B, H, E, Z, W, P, Q, R, N, I

**Definitions**

Imagine that we have a 3x3 Grid to place the coins in, it can be represented by one dimensional array: List<> of Coin that has elements from 0 to 8.

A bingo: bingo is exactly like the win condition in tic-tac-toe, a bingo can occur to a color. Example:

[image: grid and bingo]

**The Problem**

The user will enter what bingos and what letters they want, for example, a user might enter:

- Bingos: Red and Green
- Letters: D, A, C, G, Q, R, J, T, I

The program should generate solution(s), if there is a solution, solution for example above:

[image: example solution]

How do I achieve this? The user's conditions are dynamic, they can ask for any color bingo and they'll list the letters they want.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework problem......So, what have you tried? Stackoverlow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @mituw16 Well I just don't know how to begin, I'm not asking for the full solution.

Comment: You gotta tag it as code golf if you want someone to write the solution for you ;)

Comment: in order to begin think - how would I do this with paper and pencil. Then convert that manual process into code in your preferred language

Comment: maybe even make 26 colored coins out of paper and a 3 * 3 grid. Physically try it out and see what the process feels like

Comment: @pm100 The problem is I'll need to do a lot of "if this then this", because I can't know the user's conditions

Comment: I'm thinking of genetic algorithms

Comment: "the program should generate solution(s)" Which is it you are after. A solution or all possible solutions? Also unclear, can they ask for the same bingo colour more than once? Is the number of bingos to be met exactly or as a minimum?

Comment: I'd start by sorting the provided letters by colour, The target bingos with the least number of letters provided will have the least number of possible placements.

Comment: @ROX All possible solutions would be best, user cannot repeat same color bingo.

Comment: If you don't know how to get started, there is probably an easier version of the problem that you DO know how to get started on, so do that. Your task is a more complicated version of tic tac toe. Can you write a tic tac toe program?  If you can do that, then you can adapt your solution to this problem. If you can't do that, then again, simplify the problem. If you have to go back to "hello world", do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Here's the list of things to do for you:**

- *do yourself a favor* : **understand the code instead of simply copy/paste**
- implement the diagonal check
- adjust the predicate for validity to suit your needs
- fix all the potential bugs
- bonus points if you can extend it to report per column/row/diagonal validity
- test, test, test ! (only tested basic cases)
- throw a party :)

**Color**

```
public enum CoinColor
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}
```

**Letter**

```
public enum CoinLetter
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H,
    I,
    J,
    K,
    L,
    M,
    N,
    O,
    P,
    Q,
    R,
    S,
    T,
    U,
    V,
    W,
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

**Coin**

```
public sealed class Coin
{
    internal Coin(CoinColor color, CoinLetter letter)
    {
        Color = color;
        Letter = letter;
    }

    public CoinColor Color { get; }
    public CoinLetter Letter { get; }

    private bool Equals(Coin other)
    {
        return Color == other.Color && Letter == other.Letter;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Coin) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((int) Color * 397) ^ (int) Letter;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Coin left, Coin right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Coin left, Coin right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(Color)}: {Color}, {nameof(Letter)}: {Letter}";
    }
}
```

**Helper**

```
public static class Coins
{
    public static Coin[][] All => new[]
    {
        AllRed,
        AllGreen,
        AllBlue
    };

    public static Coin[] AllRed { get; } =
    {
        RedS, RedD, RedA, RedC, RedY, RedU, RedL, RedJ, RedO
    };

    public static Coin[] AllGreen { get; } =
    {
        GreenG, GreenX, GreenB, GreenH, GreenE, GreenZ, GreenW, GreenP, GreenQ, GreenR, GreenN, GreenI
    };

    public static Coin[] AllBlue { get; } =
    {
        BlueF, BlueT, BlueV, BlueM, BlueK
    };

    public static Coin RedA => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.A);
    public static Coin RedC => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.C);
    public static Coin RedD => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.D);
    public static Coin RedJ => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.J);
    public static Coin RedL => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.L);
    public static Coin RedO => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.O);
    public static Coin RedS => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.S);
    public static Coin RedU => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.U);
    public static Coin RedY => new Coin(CoinColor.Red, CoinLetter.Y);
    public static Coin GreenB => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.B);
    public static Coin GreenE => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.E);
    public static Coin GreenG => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.G);
    public static Coin GreenH => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.H);
    public static Coin GreenI => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.I);
    public static Coin GreenN => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.N);
    public static Coin GreenP => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.P);
    public static Coin GreenQ => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.Q);
    public static Coin GreenR => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.R);
    public static Coin GreenW => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.W);
    public static Coin GreenX => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.X);
    public static Coin GreenZ => new Coin(CoinColor.Green, CoinLetter.Z);
    public static Coin BlueF => new Coin(CoinColor.Blue, CoinLetter.F);
    public static Coin BlueK => new Coin(CoinColor.Blue, CoinLetter.K);
    public static Coin BlueM => new Coin(CoinColor.Blue, CoinLetter.M);
    public static Coin BlueT => new Coin(CoinColor.Blue, CoinLetter.T);
    public static Coin BlueV => new Coin(CoinColor.Blue, CoinLetter.V);
}
```

**Game**

```
public class Game
{
    public Game() : this(new Coin[GridWidth, GridHeight])
    {
    }

    public Game(Coin[,] grid)
    {
        if (grid == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(grid));

        if (grid.GetUpperBound(0) != GridWidth - 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(grid));

        if (grid.GetUpperBound(1) != GridHeight - 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(grid));

        Grid = grid;
    }

    private static int GridWidth { get; } = 3;
    private static int GridHeight { get; } = 3;
    private static int GridExtent => 3;
    private Coin[,] Grid { get; }

    public Coin GetCoin(int col, int row)
    {
        Check(col, row);

        var coin = Grid[col, row];

        return coin;
    }

    public void SetCoin(Coin coin, int col, int row)
    {
        Check(col, row);

        Grid[col, row] = coin;
    }

    public bool Check()
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < GridWidth; col++)
            if (CheckCol(col))
                return true;

        for (var row = 0; row < GridHeight; row++)
            if (CheckRow(row))
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    private bool CheckCol(int col)
    {
        CheckColIndex(col);

        var coins = new Coin[GridHeight];

        for (var row = 0; row < GridHeight; row++)
            coins[row] = GetCoin(col, row);

        var check = Check(coins);

        return check;
    }

    private bool CheckRow(int row)
    {
        CheckRowIndex(row);

        var coins = new Coin[GridWidth];

        for (var column = 0; column < GridWidth; column++)
            coins[column] = GetCoin(column, row);

        var check = Check(coins);

        return check;
    }

    private bool Check(Coin[] coins)
    {
        if (coins == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(coins));

        var any = Coins.All.Any(s => s.Where(coins.Contains).Distinct().Count() == GridExtent);

        return any;
    }

    private static void Check(int col, int row)
    {
        CheckColIndex(col);
        CheckRowIndex(row);
    }

    private static void CheckColIndex(int col)
    {
        if (col < 0 || col >= GridWidth)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(col));
    }

    private static void CheckRowIndex(int row)
    {
        if (row < 0 || row >= GridHeight)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row));
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
internal class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        var allGood = new[,]
        {
            {Coins.RedS, Coins.RedD, Coins.RedA},
            {Coins.GreenG, Coins.GreenX, Coins.GreenB},
            {Coins.BlueF, Coins.BlueT, Coins.BlueV}
        };

        var allFalse = new[,]
        {
            {Coins.RedS, Coins.RedS, Coins.RedA},
            {Coins.GreenG, Coins.GreenG, Coins.GreenB},
            {Coins.BlueF, Coins.BlueF, Coins.BlueV}
        };

        foreach (var grid in new[] {allGood, allFalse})
        {
            var game = new Game(grid);

            var check = game.Check();

            Console.WriteLine(check);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You welcome :-)